# Loading more items for an activity feed that uses a global page counter

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this script which is for a news feed. A button click will grab more data from the server if there is any and then add it to the box. It doesn't allow any more than 10 pages of results currently and how to properly store that page counter is what this question is about.  `loadMoreFeedItems()` is the function attached to the `onclick` event of the aforementioned button.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    window.page = 0;

    function loadMoreFeedItems() {
        var options = {};
        options.page = window.page;
        $.ajax({
            url: "home/feed",
            data: options,
            dataType: "html",
            success: function (data) {
                // Code to append the data received into the feed element
                window.page++;
                // Code to hide "load more" button if window.page exceeds 10
            }
        });
    }

    (function () {
        loadMoreFeedItems();
    })();

</script>
```

So I did a little reading about global variables in JavaScript<sup>[[1]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3352020/what-is-the-best-way-to-set-a-global-variable-in-javascript)[[2]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4862193/javascript-global-variables)[[3]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5786851/define-global-variable-in-a-javascript-function)</sup>  and while this works, I got the vibe that this could be problematic, so I'm wondering if there is a better way. One alternative I thought of was to create some kind of hidden  that stores the value in page rather than the browser, and then I'd modify/retrieve it using a jQuery selector, but that seems even dirtier.

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't have anything to do with ajax or the options exactly, just about "counting up" so i will show my example using a function called `countUp` which logs ever increasing numbers.

In short you can make `page` a member of `countUp`. You will recall that in javascript that functions are very much first class citizens and they are objects. Its easier to see this of course if you write your function definitions like:

```
var countUp = function () { /* .. function body */ }
```

So the variable `countUp` can have in it any number of members. The member we are interested in is `page` or more precisely `this.page`. So lets put this all together.

```
var countUp = function ()
{
    this.page = (typeof this.page !== "undefined") ? this.page : 0;
    this.page++;
    console.log(this.page);
}

countUp();
countUp();
countUp();
// logs 1 2 3
```

Comment: This is a very bad recommendation. Creating a class that when instantiated increases a counter? That is completely illogical and a huge misuse of JavaScript's OO features. **All the code needs to do when counting is increment**.

Comment: @SirPython sorry but you are very unclear about a few things. One is posted as a comment to your Answer. And the other all functions are objects in javascript. The only difference is that shorthand `function foo()` peculates to the top of the scope, while `var foo = function()` does not. They are both  objects of type `Function`. Objects have members this is a very basic principle of OOP.

Comment: @SirPython another point of misunderstanding you have is that talk about "Classes" in javascript When in reality javascript uses prototypes for an inheritance model.

Comment: When talking about JavaScript, "classes" usually refer to functions that are used to instantiate new objects. And yes, I know how JavaScript works and that "everything is an object".

Comment: Well i am obviously not instantiating a new class on **each** call. See the terinary expression, i am reusing `this.page` exactly because `countUp` is an object. At any rate I think its time for me to step away from this thread, but hopefully I can make it constructive for everyone by pointing out this great resource on really understanding javascript. "You Don't Know Javascript" https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS

Comment: You are instantiating a new object on each call. You are setting the `page` property each time `countUp` is called, because you use it like `this.page`.  My point is you shouldn't be storing information each call, especially because you don't use the instantiated object. What the OP does is perfectly fine, and you are over-complicating it. And by the way, great resource!

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> var options = {};
> options.page = window.page;
> ```

This is kind of a dirty way to populate an object. It's just like creating a blank array only to populate it's indexes in the line after, like this:

```
var arr = [];
arr[0] = ...;
arr[1] = ...;
```

That's a little gross looking, right? It would look a lot more clean if you just setup the `page` property as soon as the object was created, like this:

```
var options = {page:window.page};
```

---

Why are you storing the `page` variable in the `window` object? There is no need (at least with the code that is shown) to have that variable in scope for every other script in that page: only this script is accessing it, so it should be declared with `var`.

That would look like this:

```
var page = 0;
```

Now, when accessing the page variable, you no longer use `window.page`, you just use `page`.

---

Comment: If you change `window.page` to `var page;` on the same line as Ty has it, you are not changing anything in the design, `page` would still be global in either case. This answer is wrong.